# Specifying relationships in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, relationship

I'm trying to figure out the best way to represent this in MySQL. I have two tables: `clients` and `accounts`. Any `client` can "own" zero, one or more `accounts`. Two different `clients` could potentially own the same `account`. So a `client` has many `accounts`, and vice versa.

So my current plan is that the `clients` table has a field `accounts`, which contains a comma-separated list of `account` `id`s. This works perfectly.

But would it make more sense to have a separate table (e.g. `client_accounts`), with two fields, `client_id` and `account_id`?

This is for a database that will never have millions of rows, so efficiency isn't a huge factor.

Comment: An associative table is generally viewed as "better" than CSV.  This mechanism style is how I write permissions systems for my applications.  A users table, a roles table(each permission), and an associative table which contains one record for each user/permission granted.

Comment: Don't use comma-separated values in a table column.... it inevitably creates problems when trying to update, and can't be searched easily because you can't index the individual values, so search performance is slow.... use an `account_client` cross-reference table, with a `many-to-many` relationship

Comment: Look up database normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, if you want to keep your db integrity, any tables with a relation of n:n ( many to many ) or 1:n should use an extra table that links the two of them.

Comment: This is the 'associative table' mentioned above by @Andrew Coder

Answer (score 0):

> But would it make more sense to have a separate table (e.g. `client_accounts`), with two fields, `client_id` and `account_id`

This is exact way you should do this. This way you can make better use of indexes and gain faster joins. You will also save some efford on data-secure, once you will need in this table an UNIQUE on **combination of both columns** to not duplicate data:

```
/* ... */ ADD idx_pair UNIQUE(client_id,account_id)
```

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on setting both columns to be `UNIQUE`? Won't this stop me applying the same `account` to more than one `client`?

Comment: Set the __combination__ of both columns to be unique